# Python: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: python, xml

I have the given sample code(which contains an xml variable) and I want to read some of the attributes of the Xml and then update them. Once updated I want to post them using requests.post.
I get the error as "not well formed" token, and I am not able to parse the xml.
please suggest what is wrong in the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
dataxml = """<APIDataMessage MessageID="747950743" SensorID=extref MessageDate=messagedate State="16" SignalStrength=random.randint(40,70) Voltage="2.83" Battery=random.randint(80,90) Data=random.randint(27,40) DisplayData="67.1° F" PlotValue="67.1" MetNotificationRequirements="False" GatewayID="106558" DataValues="19.5" DataTypes="TemperatureData" PlotValues="67.1" PlotLabels="Fahrenheit" />"""
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
root = etree.fromstring(dataxml, parser=parser)
root.set('SignalStrength',100)
print etree.tostring(root)
```

Comment: 1. `SensorID=extref MessageDate=messagedate` accornf to to XML documentation attribute value must be given in the `"` e.g. <test SensorID="extref" MessageDate="messagedate" />  . This is missing in the `dataxml`.

2. what is `random.randint(27,40)` means how this will work in XML ?

Comment: random.randint would return a random value between the range. But yeah I understood it has to be string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me following need to do in code:

1. XML attribute value must be provided into `""` e.g. `<test id="12">`. This is missng in input `SensorID=extref MessageDate=messagedate`
2. Evaluate value of random first and then add value to string to create complete tag.
3. Need string in `set` method i.e. `root.set('SignalStrength','100')`

**Demo**:

```
dataxml = """<APIDataMessage MessageID="747950743" SensorID="extref"\
 MessageDate="messagedate" State="16" SignalStrength="%s" \
Voltage="2.83" Battery="%s" Data="%s" DisplayData="67.1° F" PlotValue="67.1" \
MetNotificationRequirements="False" GatewayID="106558" DataValues="19.5" \
DataTypes="TemperatureData" PlotValues="67.1" PlotLabels="Fahrenheit" />"""\
%(random.randint(40,70), random.randint(80,90), random.randint(27,40))


from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
root = etree.fromstring(dataxml, parser=parser)
root.set('SignalStrength',"100")
print etree.tostring(root)
```