# python - xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree

parser = ETree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ETree.fromstring("C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/test_xml.xml", parser=parser)
print(ETree.tostring(tree))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXX/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 6, in <module>
    tree = ETree.fromstring("C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/test_xml.xml", parser=parser)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1314, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2
```

I checked probably all questions to this error message on StackOverflow, nothing helped:

- I tried to edit file with another editor (as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662942/xml-etree-elementtree-parseerror-not-well-formed));
- I added this line: `tree.set('SignalStrength',"100")` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033751/python-xml-etree-elementtree-parseerror-not-well-formed-invalid-token/35034308#35034308));
- Tried to add DOCTYPE;
- Checked the file with [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input);

etc.

Then I tried to import another XML file with completely another structure - and error message remained the same - even the position: `line 1, column 2`.

And then I tried to change the file's name to the non-existent - and the error message remained the same! So it is not a problem of file, it is something else. And I can't understand what.

**P.S.** This is one of the XML files I used:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**EDIT:** 
Probably I can't import file in the way I did in the fromstring() function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`parse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) instead of `fromstring()` when parsing from a file.

`parse()` returns an `ElementTree` instance and [`tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) expects an `Element` instance.

This code works:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree

parser = ETree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ETree.parse("test_xml.xml", parser=parser)
print(ETree.tostring(tree.getroot()))
```